# How to distribute width in according to module count?

Tags: templates, twitter-bootstrap-2, positions

I am trying to make a joomla template. I am also using bootstrap v2.3.2. I want to make a design 3/12-6/12-3/12 distribution. 
I am checking if any modules are positioned on the left and right columns

```
$span = 12;

if ($this->countModules('right')) $span -= 3;
if ($this->countModules('left'))  $span -= 3;

<?php if ($this->countModules('left')): ?>
    <div id="sidebarleft" class="span3">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" style="well" />
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div id="content" class="<?php echo $span; ?>">
    <jdoc:include type="message" />
    <jdoc:include type="component" />
</div>

<?php if ($this->countModules('right')) : ?>
    <div id="sidebarright" class="span3">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right" style="none" />
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have assigned a `mod_articles_category` module to left position but it is empty. So the module is not shown. But joomla thinks that there is a module in that position and it has to shrink content with.

How can I use the space if module is not shown on a page?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right, this snippet should help (note, I haven't run the code)

```
<?php
if ($this->countModules('left')) {
   $modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('left');
   $modulesContent  = array();
   foreach ($modules as $module) {
      $content = JModuleHelper::renderModule($module, array('style' => 'well'));
      if(!empty($content)) {
         $modulesContent[] = $content;
      }
   }
}
?>
<?php if(!empty($modulesContent)) : ?>
   <div id="sidebarleft" class="span3">
      <?php foreach ($modulesContent as $content) : ?>
        <?php echo $content; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: To keep with the format of the original question, you would also then want to subtract 3 from `$span` in the bottom if statement (once we have shown that the modules have content) to adjust the width of the main column.

Comment: Also note that this would think that the modules had content even if it just had an empty `div` tag in the module, so it may not help much more than `countModules`.